# issue with javascript string isolation

Tags: javascript

I want to grab the first set of characters before the "/" but both the values before and after keep being displayed. how would I do that?

```
var str="http://www.youtube.com/fdgfdgfdghgfh";
var fileName_image = str;
var n = fileName_image.substring(fileName_image.lastIndexOf('http://') + 7);
var f = n.substring(n.charAt('/'));
```

What I am getting with the above is: www.youtube.com/fdgfdgfdghgfh

what I would like to get is www.youtube.com

Comment: @JuanMendes That's a matter of syntax. Instead of "I want to grab..." do you want OP to ask "How can I grab...?"

Comment: @Matt No it isn't, the wording is confusing, structuring your question as a question makes it easier to understand, just adding how do I do that? doesn't help

Comment: Change charAt to indexOf or change var f = n.substring(n.charAt('/')); to var f = n.split('/')[1]; change [1] to [0] to get the stuff before the slash

Comment: @JuanMendes then it's not just a matter of adding a question mark, is it? It's a matter of OP *clarifying* his question.

Comment: indexOf outputs the last value and not the first. so i get /fdgfdgfdghgfh

Comment: @Matt sorry for my sarcasm, you can read my comment as 'Your question is not clear'

Comment: @JuanMendes lol your comment was not clear :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
var f = n.substring(n.charAt('/'));
```

to

```
var f = n.split('/')[1];
```

change [1] to [0] to get the stuff before the slash

Alternative to get the stuff before the / is

```
var f = n.substring(0,n.indexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 3):

While you can do this without regular expressions, it's going to be a lot of slow, confusing code.  This kind of string processing is *exactly* why regular expressions exist.  So use 'em.

```
// input string
var str = "http://www.youtube.com/fdgfdgfdghgfh";

// matching regex
//   note that forward slashes must be escaped
//   capture text between "http://" (http:\/\/) and the next "/" (\/)
//   use [1] index to retrieve the first captured string (.+?)
var result = str.match(/^http:\/\/(.+?)\//)[1];

// log result
console.log(result); // "www.youtube.com"
```

Comment: It's not slower, using `indexOf` is faster if you can get away with it. It probably won't make a difference in this case, so I would use a RegExp since it is slightly more clear (if you understand RegExps well) Does my answer look complicated?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to return www.youtube.com? Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/HqSev ???

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "http://www.youtube.com/fdgfdgfdghgfh"; 
var start = "http://".length;
// Grabs everything after http:// up until the next slash
str.substring(start, str.indexOf("/", start));
```

I like @AlexWayne's approach, probably would use that. However, this answer shows you where you were going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the last line with if you are looking for string "fdgfdgfdghgfh":

var f = n.substring(n.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);